# google map ios sdk: could not get current user location?

Tags: ios8, google-maps-sdk-ios

```
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
println("ml")
println(mapView.myLocation)
```

I got nil for mapView.myLocation and I'm using an iPod for testing not an emulator.
The iPod's 'location services' is on.

I'm using xcode 6 beta 5 and targeting ios 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is I need to declare NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in info.plist for ios 8. Then everything else works!

Answer (score 2):

Enabling location services does not mean you get a location right away. It usually takes a little bit of time to get a location. You need to enable KVO observing on that property to be notified of changes.